# Add a "Reject and Flag Original Post" button to Suggested Edit Review Queue Interface

Tags: feature-request, review, edits

### TL;DR

I am requesting that a button be added to the Suggested Edit Review Queue interface to reject an edit *and* flag the post that the edit was made on.

### Background

I started working through the Suggested Review Queue recently, and I've noticed that there are often edits made on posts that should just be deleted or closed. I feel that time spent "polishing turds" is wasted, both for the editor and edit reviewers. I currently handle these by rejecting the edit, visiting the original post, and flagging the question myself.

This three-step process occurs regularly enough that I think it should be made easier.

Therefore, I am requesting that a button be added to the Suggested Edit Review Queue toolbar for flagging posts. I also suggest that this button reject the edit by default, with a message similar to the following:

> This edit was made on a post that should have been flagged for deletion or closing.

There is a related discussion on Meta Stack Overflow [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261812/2615940).

### Expected Impact

**Pros**

1. Reviewers can get through the queue a little bit faster by reducing the amount of navigation required to help maintain site quality
2. Having the option more easily accessible will encourage reviewers to consider deleting posts that are not up to site quality standards

**Cons**

1. If edit reviewers find it easier to flag posts, the number of posts getting sent into the Low Quality Post and Close Vote queues may increase

My response: We as a community seem to have already decided that the cost of review effort is worth the benefit of having a cleaner site. I believe that this feature request coincides with that sentiment. Additionally, the user that suggested the edit will see this new reason for why their edit was rejected, which will discourage them from making further edits on unsalvageable posts, reducing the size of the Suggested Edit Review queue.

2. Adding a flag option may muddle the scope of what edit reviewers are supposed to do

My response: I agree with the assertion made by [this MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261926/2615940) answer, which is that the purpose of edit reviews is to just the quality of *the edit*, not the quality of *the overall post*. However, I am not trying to imply that edit reviewers should *necessarily* begin judging the original post. But if, in the course of judging the review, it becomes obvious that the whole post is garbage, then I think flagging the post is a reasonable action and we should encourage that behavior.

**Side Note**
I do not have 3k reputation on any site, so I don't know exactly how the close vote and delete vote interfaces work. For users over 3k, I would suggest that the "Reject and Flag Original Post" button be replaced with a "Reject and Vote to Close Original Post" or "Reject and Vote to Delete Original Post" button, or something similar.

### Conclusion

I acknowledge that flagging/deleting/closing original posts is beyond the scope of the Suggested Edit Review Queue, but I think it is a useful behavior that we should encourage in edit reviewers by making it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the whole post is garbage *and the edit does nothing to change that* then reject it:

[image: no improvement whatsoever]

That's your primary duty in suggested edit review. Yes, there are frequently posts that show up in there that could warrant other actions - flags, upvotes, downvotes - but as a reviewer those things are distractions: determining whether or not an edit is useful is plenty hard enough.

*Once you've done that,* feel free to click through to the post and do whatever else you see as necessary.

Comment: Fair enough. I had thought about the scope of responsibility issue at an abstract level, but not necessarily about how the resulting extra button could be a distraction at the UI level. I agree that reviewing suggested edits is difficult, it's certainly the queue that I move through most slowly, and that another button would certainly not make *reviewing the edit itself* any easier. Good response.